# C++ ¿Como hago el entorno visual de un programa?

Tags: c++

llevo un tiempo programando en C++ y estoy empezando a ver C#

Sinceramente estoy interesado en hacer programas de escritorio, pero no tengo idea de como se hace el entorno visual del programa; o sea: botones, efectos, imágenes, sonidos, etc

¿Requiere de librerías o de algo aparte de C++?

Comment: Prueba con SFML (Simple and Fast Multimedia Library) como punto de partida. https://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: quizas QT, https://www.qt.io/es/ que te auna el diseño grafico y el desarrollo del codigo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El estándar C++ no dispone de una librería para realizar interfaces gráficas.

Las únicas opciones pasan por empaparse sobre cómo funciona la API gráfica del sistema operativo (winapi en el caso de Windows) o usar una librería de terceros que encapsule la complejidad de hablar directamente con la API del SO.

Yo te recomendaría usar una librería de terceros y, en este caso, hay multitud de posibildades. Algunas de las más conocidas son:

- [Qt](https://www.qt.io/es/): Framework multiplataforma y muy completo.
- [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/): librería específica para interfaces gráficas. Multiplataforma
- [MFC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Classes): Librería específica de Microsoft, disponible únicamente bajo Windows y licencia.
- [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/): Librería gráfica multiplataforma que proviene de entornos Linux

Comment: gracias por la ayuda eferion la verdad es que estoy algo perdido en el tema, las investigare